# Maths/Programming recursion question

Tags: recursion

I know this is a programming question but it seems to be more on the mathematical side ( recursion ) I was hoping someone would be able to explain it to me since it will probably be on my exam tomorrow.

http://vvcap.net/db/kIcAQxI5nJGOdN_l18Zb.htp

From 1,1 i cannot do it since the answer is 0 and i seem to get 0, -1 since a becomes 0 and b becomes -1....

This would be an absolute massive help if someone could explain to me where i'm going wrong because it will be worth 10 marks in the exam!

Comment: $f(1,1) = f(f(1-1,1-1),1-1) = f(f(0,0),0) = f(0,0) = 0$

Comment: Marc, Sorry could you be a bit more clearer don't really understand this. But thanks for helping!

Comment: you've done 1-1 for the final one but b is now 0 so you do 0-1 don't you :O?

Comment: I have replaced all the variables simultaneously which gives you all zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first you call `f(1,1)`. In this case, you have to evaluate the *else* branch where you have `return f(f(a-1,b-1),b-1).` Since `a=1` and `b=1` you can replace these `a-1` and `b-1` with its actual value `0`. This gives you call `return f(f(0,0),0)`. Since there is no assignment of any variable, you can replace these values simultaneously. Now, you have to evaluate this `return f(f(0,0),0)` in two steps. First you replace `f(0,0)` by its return value `0`. This gives you `return f(0,0)`. Again, since `f(0,0) -> 0` you have `return 0`.

Comment: Hey thanks! but, if you have 1,2 this would mean your output would be 0,1,1 so how could i compute an answer from these values? thank you so much btw!

Comment: You are doing the same evaluations. $f(1,2) = f(f(1-1,2-1),2-1) = f(f(0,1),1)$. Since $f(0,1) = 0$ you get $f(1,2) = f(0,1) = 0$. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: not really haha sorry. I don't really see how f(0,1)=0 and then you go on from that point so none of it really makes sense :P

Comment: Ooooops. I just realised that I read your code a bit wrong (poor resolution). sorry for the confusion. Okay, we have of course $f(0,1) = 1$. Then gives us the following situation: $f(1,2)=f(f(1−1,2−1),2−1)=f(f(0,1),1) = f(1,1) = f(f(1-1,1-1),1-1) = f(f(0,0),0) = f(0,0)$.

Comment: For $f(2,2) = f(f(2-1,2-1),2-1) = f(f(1,1),1) = f(f(f(1-1,1-1),1-1),1) = f(f(f(0,0),0),1) = f(f(0,0),1) = f(0,1) = 1$

Comment: Wow, ok, thanks! the only thing im really unsure off is the final 1-1 since in the other one you stick with the original value which in this case b originally was 2 so why do you do 1-1? and not 1-2 ?

Comment: And i follow your 2,2 where u get 1-1,1-1,1-1 until you randomly get the value 1?

Comment: This is because you have to do the recursion as often as needed. For example $f(f(1,1),1)$. First we have to evaluate $f(1,1)=f(f(1−1,1−1),1−1)=f(f(0,0),0) = f(0,0)=0$. We can use this fact in our original problem $f(f(1,1),1)$ and replace $f(1,1)$ with $0$. Thus, we get $f(0,1)=1$.

Comment: So, I have to go. Good luck with your exams!

Comment: I still don't fully understand where the 1 is coming from in 2,2. The only logical guess i think off is you're doing 2-1 for the final one ? but then there's only 3 sums and they are 1-1, 1-1 and 1-1 =/ it's nearly 1am! but i don't want to go offline till i understand this: D